# nyc should be a tag synonym for New York City

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms

I suggest we make [nyc](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nyc) a tag synonym for [new-york-city](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-york-city) as it is commonly a synonym in real life. I don't have the rep yet to do it myself.

Comment: +1, great idea.

Comment: Since the votes indicate a consensus on this, I created the tag synonyms.

Answer (score 5):

I think it makes sense. Moreover, [new-york-city](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-york-city) [is already synonymous](https://travel.stackexchange.com/tags/new-york-city/synonyms) to [manhattan](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manhattan) and [brooklyn](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brooklyn). [The mods](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) can define synonyms instantaneously. If we get consensus here they'll take care of it. ;)

Comment: +1, What about the other 3 boroughs?

Comment: I thoguht any user with over [2.5k](http://travel.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) rep can do it? (aka please do it yourself :D)

Comment: Tag synonyms are weird. Any user with X rep in at least Y answers in that particular tag can *suggest* a synonym. It then needs to be voted by similar users at least Z times before it gets approved. To accelerate the process you can sacrifice a goat to Jeff, drink the tears of a thousand mermaids and chant the gods of Valhalla. Or you can ask a site moderator. Both actions are  equivalent. :D

Comment: @GayotFow Nobody created the synonyms, or the tags, yet. ;)

Comment: @JoErNanO, yesterday I made the 'nhs' tag in Expats because it's now very relevant.  And I filled out the description without problems.  It may be a synonym to health insurance, but the creation is way over my head.  But if there's a tag for Brooklyn (my birthplace by the way) and Manhattan, then we would want the other boroughs represented as well.  Just an opinion...

Comment: @GayotFow I agree. What I am saying is that it makes sense to cross that bridge when we get there. In other words: let's wait for the tags to be created (usually this happens when users post relevant questions) before we think about creating synonyms for them. ;)

Comment: @JoErNanO, I'm in. Agreed. But what if somebody wants to make a tag like 'turtle-bay' or 'bowery' or 'hells-kitchen' or (heaven help us) 'flatbush'? It could result into a recursive descent down to '5th-ave-at-55th-street'.  That would be bad.  Boroughs are a fine level to stop the recursion.